# Spark, docker: application is RUNNING, but initial job has not accepted any resources

Tags: apache-spark

I've setup a spark cluster in docker with 1 master and 7 workers on my desktop running linux.

When I send jobs to it, even if the status of the application is RUNNING, the driver complains about "Initial job has not accepted any resources; check your cluster UI to ensure that workers are registered and have sufficient resources"and it doesn't process the steps.

The UI shows 1 of the workers using 2/2 cores and 1024MB/1024MB of memory, the application shows as RUNNING (but never ends, and the steps are 0/2). The rest of the workers are idleing.

I've tried stopping firewalld and restarting docker, to see if that was causing the problem, but it wasn't.

The same configuration under WSL on my local machine works great (always 2 cores, 1G of RAM each worker, same jobs).

May you please help me?

Thanks :)

EDIT: the very same cluster, if interrogated locally (i.e. driver pointing to spark://127.0.0.1:7077), works flawlessly.

EDIT 2:
another info: reading the worker logs, I found out what could be the problem: the driver url is set to "spark://CoarseGrainedScheduler@172.25.230.63:35625" - the problem here is that the worker thus tries to connect to the given IP, which is not reachable but if within the Windows machine hosting the WSL2 instance, from which the driver is run. I've thus tried to set spark.driver.host to the Window's LAN IP address, but spark won't be able to bind the random port on that address (as it's invisible to the WSL2 machine). Any clue on how to set the driver URL on the worker?

Comment: I'm having the same problem as you! Have you solved this problem?

Comment: Hello SecY, I abandoned this architecture time ago, but I remember the issue was that the requester, running on your local machine / notepad, need to be contacted directly by the workers. This means that the simpliest way to do this is to configure Docker to work in a bridge network and pointing to the cluster not via 127.0.0.1, but to the allocated IP by the DHCP. Not the simpliest way though, thus the decision to abandon the architecture.